# How to make TextView value in different fragment to be same

Tags: android

Its seems like simple thing to do,but i can't fix it.So please help me.I have two fragments

```
FruitsFragment.java
VegetableFragment.java
```

And each have layout with TextView 'total'. Each fragment have listview with plus button.whenever the plus button is clicked the total value get incremented.But when another fragment is selected the value for total is not updated.I want the value of total to be same for both fragment.

FruitsFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.act_layout, container, false);
        total = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.total_amount);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter1(getActivity(),arrItems,images,prices,weight);
        listAdapter.setTextView(total);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(this);

    checkout = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.checkout);


    checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Checkout.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

And ListAdapter.java is

public class ListAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {

public int qty=1;

```
public ArrayList<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private TextView total;
private String[] listViewItems,prices,weight;
TypedArray images;
public static int pValue;
private Context context;
public static boolean t=false;
CustomButtonListener customButtonListener;

public void setTextView(TextView total)
{
    this.total = total;
}



public ListAdapter1(Context context, String[] listViewItems, TypedArray images, String[] weight, String[] prices) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listViewItems = listViewItems;
    this.images = images;
    this.prices=prices;
    this.weight=weight;
}

public void setCustomButtonListener(CustomButtonListener customButtonListner)
{
    this.customButtonListener = customButtonListner;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return listViewItems[position];
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;


    final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.product,parent,false);
        listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
        listViewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName)
        listViewHolder.tvPrices = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
        listViewHolder.btnPlus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_addnew);
        listViewHolder.edTextQuantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
        listViewHolder.btnMinus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_remove);
        row.setTag(listViewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        row=convertView;
        listViewHolder= (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    try{

        listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText(quantity.get(position) );

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    listViewHolder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(context, " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            int mValue = Integer.parseInt(listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString());
            if (mValue <=0) {
                System.out.println("not valid");
                mValue=0;
                listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText("" +mValue);
            }
            else{
                pValue=pValue/mValue;
                mValue--;
                pValue=pValue*mValue;
                total.setText(String.valueOf(pValue));
                System.out.println("mvalue after reducing-----------"+mValue);
                System.out.println("pvalue-----------"+pValue);
                listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText( "" +mValue );

            }
        }
    });

    listViewHolder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(context, " " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            int mValue = Integer.parseInt(listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString());
            pValue=Integer.parseInt(listViewHolder.tvPrices.getText().toString());
            mValue++;
            listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText("" + mValue);
            System.out.println("mValue after increment---" + mValue);
            pValue=pValue*mValue;
            System.out.println("pvalue-----------"+pValue);
            total.setText(String.valueOf(pValue));
        }
    });
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Put some code please.

Comment: how you are maintain this value show some efforts

Comment: Save your total value in **static** variable and share among screens **OR** save in shared preference and populate from them.

Comment: Create that TextView in activity instead of creating it in different fragments.